# Sony sony-smarteyeglass other smartphones

Tags: sony, sony-smarteyeglass

is it possible to run Sony-smarteyeglass SDK on devices of other manufactures or can it run on only Sony devices like SonyExperia?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Sony SmartEyeglass with any android smartphone running API level 19 (Android 4.4) and above. You have to install the SmartConnect and SmartEyeglass App on this device.

If you just want to check out SmartEyeglass development try the Sony SmartEyeglass emulator, which is included in the SonySmartEyeglass SDK.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use Sony SmartEyeglass and its SDK, with any android smartphone with version 4.4 and above.

You only need to install SmartConnect on your device :

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sonyericsson.extras.liveware

Answer (score 0):

But it is not possible to run on iOS devices as of now.